Mathematical interpretation and Fuzzy logic interpretation of d err/dt or change of error
Thank you for the possibility to ask a question.
I am new at this forum.
Currently I am scratching the surface of fuzzy logic with the idea to go deeper an deeper.
From calculus, I understand that a function derivative is positive if the slope at any point is positive and vicevice viceversa.
Based on reading different online articles and books, apparently, that meaning is different form fuzzy logic.
Les's take the attached picture whic i found online that render how evolve error as response to the impulse. According this graph the A area shows derr/dt  or CE NEGATIVE under the sp or reference value and does not change the sign even in B area over that reference.
According to the article under the reference value err is decrasingemphasized text and over the referenc is increasing.
On the other hand the conventional way to expressing the error in control theory is
err = sp - proces variable.
and the pic aggre with the fact that in A the error is positive while in B is negative.
How can should be interpreted both meaning of derivative sign?
Thank you for any help.
Impulse respons of a feedback system

if the error is positive below the reference, and the error is going from positive to zero (region A), then the error is decreasing (CE is negative). Is that what you are asking? It is kind of unclear what your question is.
